# Screen offset to the left

Tags: 16.04, lts

I've just finished installing ubuntu server and I've come across a problem. My screen is offset by a fair amount, I've tried commands such as:
xrandr --size 1920x1080
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --set underscan auto
xrandr -q

All of these out put the same error, however since my screen is offset I can't read what it says. All I can see is:
open display

Any ideas what the error says/how to fix the screen offset problem?

Comment: Did you test replacing your GPU or your screen?
Just to be sure it is not a hardware-related problem.